# Why is it "have a care", and not "have care"?

Tags: grammar, phrases

I was reading The Lord of the Rings (or actually I was listening to Andy Serkis' reading of it), wherein Frodo once says to Gollum as a warning, "have a care". I instantly perceived it to be a dated expression, equivalent to "beware", or in more modern terms, "be careful".

My question is: Why is it "have a care", and not something like "have care" or even "take care"? To me, "a care" makes "care" sounds like a countable thing, whereas I would rather treat it as uncountable and never put an article in front of it.

Comment: Back as far as Chaucer we find "a care" and it means "a concern, a particular worry".  Don't be "careless" (of your safety).  Compare the expression: "Without a care in the world", meaning "blithe"  However, we do also find "have care" and "take care", where it means "concern, solicitude, anxiety, worry". Be cautious.

Comment: I don't know the logic of it, but  Tolkien was consciously using the archaic expression for "Take care!" or "Look out!".  [This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+a+care&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows the decline in use since the early 19th century. (Recent instances are from phrases like _have a care plan_.)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the indefinite article transfers the idea of singularity to the occasion in mind. There are other examples where an indefinite article is used with a non-count usage where the usual 'single instance' explanation seems to need broadening:

- *The director spoke at the meeting today with an enormous enthusiasm*. [probably better not analysed as being one of the greatest enthusiasms attributed to the director]
- *She smiled at us with an unusual friendliness*. [probably better not analysed as being one of the greatest displays of her friendliness, but as a rare sign of any friendliness]

[UsefulEnglish](https://usefulenglish.ru/grammar/part-4-specific-use-of-a) has this to say:

> In formal writing and literary works the article a/an may be used with
> some uncountable abstract nouns to show an unusual or temporary aspect
> of something. The indefinite article here has similar meaning to:
> such, certain, special, peculiar[, unexpected]. [though an adjective such as 'unusual', 'enormous', 'rare' may be added after the article]